# Black Screen when I run Tropico 5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 64-bit, 16.04, steam, amd-processor

I recently installed Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) and downloaded some games. I opened Tropico 5 (A game that worked fine when I ran it in Windows 10) and I was shown a black screen. I could hear the sound from the game, but I couldn't see anything. I've tried a couple of solutions that I've found by browsing the internet, but neither of them have worked. 
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - I've installed all available updates.
Processor: AMD A10-4655M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics - It's quad core.
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0) - I've installed the drivers.
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 976.8GB
Other Notes:
~Steam tells me that I need to update it, yet I'm running the latest version all ready (I've checked).
~My Ubuntu root partition takes up all space on my disk (other than the space taken up by the boot and swap partitions, of course).
~I'm booting Ubuntu in UEFI mode.
~Cities Skylines works fine when I try to play that.

Thanks!
-L.J.C

Answer (score 7):

Use launch options and type this in

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.0 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=400 %command%
```

Source:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/245620/discussions/0/492379439670516309/?ctp=2

I used it, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Question - do you hear the sound playing? Do you see the mouse cursor appear from the game (looks like a big yellow/gold arrow)?

If yes then the cause is most likely an error with the game developer logo video overlay. You are actually in the menu already but you can not see it because of the video overlay bug.

At this point you can: Press Enter - wait 5 seconds - Press enter again.

This should launch the tutorial.

In the tutorial exit back to the main menue and you can load your game, start a new one (without the tutorial) etc. Everything works fine then.

My setup Arch Linux 64bit, Intel i7, NVIDIA GTX960 using NVIDIA drivers. Total playing time over 40 hours or so.....